# AsQueryable - where will be the Logic when I execute it?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, asqueryable

When I do

```
var arr = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400 };
var q = arr.AsQueryable();
```

`q` is an `IQueryable<int>` (concrete an `EnumerableQuery<int>`).
Now, when I call

```
Queryable.Sum(q)
```

where can I find the sum-Logic?
When I look into the Sum-Method, I see that there will the Expression-Tree executed with the Method Queryable.Sum.
But where can I find the Iteration over the array which will sum the values?

I understand that AsQueryable will create the Expression of the IEnumerable and Queryable.Sum() executes it with the EnumerableQuery-Provider but where is the effective Logic which will be executed?

Comment: The query is executed by the underlying `QueryProvider`. In that case I'd guess that there is a query provider that simply parses the expression tree and calls the appropriate `IEnumerable` extensions. But I did not look it up in the sources.

Comment: I thought so too - but can't find the job. I also inserted a breakpoint in Enumerable.Sum () - but was not called.

Comment: You can start in the reference source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/SequenceQuery.cs,4c59e0377c62ac70)  and scroll down to the `Execute` method and search on from there following the `EnumerableExecuter<S>`

Comment: .net core source for .`Enumerable.Sum()` is here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Sum.cs.

You could configure Visual Studio to step into the framework source but I can't remember how at the moment.

Comment: @RenéVogt I have found it now. There will be a MethodCallExpression created. With EnumerableRewriter this is then translated from Queryable.Sum() to Enumerable.Sum()